# Bash Shell Script that asks user to enter a file and then modifies said file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm just starting out and I was wondering how to create a script that will ask a user to enter a file they want to modify, take the entered file and then modify it with the parameters I set up.

Comment: Impossible to answer without defining `parameters`.

Comment: ‘Bash shell’ is a tautology. Bash stands for Bourne-Again SHell

Comment: Since you're just starting out, I would recommend that you *not* do this.  Forget about interactively prompting for anything: take input as command line arguments, or read it from stdin in a non-interactive way.  Unless you have very hard requirements that a human being be providing data, you should not handicap your tools by assuming a human is on the other end of the pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter File Name: " fname
echo $fname

#Output:
#Enter File Name: foo.txt
#foo.txt
```

Comment: I voted the answer up. I think this code is clear and simple enough, if SO or other readers can't understand this type of code, I will recommend they to do self study first, not just wait to get training as kids. But my recommend is, read the var to `name` directly, not need `fname` in between

Comment: @BMW yaa, guess i was overthinking..removed the intermediate var.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat reads the line from standard input by prompting -p's value. If you need more info checkout read's man page